# Adding myself as a Basemap Provider on Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Does leaflet.js send through any announcements or call-outs for new providers added to their repository like through email or on their landing page?

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet dev here.

No, we don't.

Leaflet is provider-agnostic. As long as you provide [OSM-style XYZ tiles, or TMS tiles](https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720), or a WMS service, Leaflet will be able to use it.

It's up to you to reach users. It's also up to you to send a pull request to be included in the [list of Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#basemap-providers), if you choose to make a Leaflet plugin for your basemaps.